# How do I check if the assigned user is the current user?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a script that approves the selected tasks. The user selects the tasks that he wants to approve from the list and clicks on a button that launches the function in javascript.

This is the code I use for approval:

```
      var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
            var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Test");
            var item;
            for (item in selectedItems)
            {
              listitem = list.getItemById(selectedItems[item].id);
              listitem.set_item('Completed',true);
              listitem.set_item('PercentComplete',1);
              listitem.set_item('Status','Completed');
              listitem.set_item('FormData','Approved');
              listitem.set_item('WorkflowOutcome','Approved');
              listitem.update();
            }
```

The problem is that a user can approve any task that is in the list.
I want to check if the current user is the same as the user to whom the task was assigned.

The task list has a field that indicates the user assigned to it. 
I want to know if there is any way to compare that field with the current user.

How can I do this using javascript?

Comment: Can you provide code sample and explain the problem in details. Also what you have tried so far.

Comment: Does the user need to be able to see Tasks they *cannot* approve within the same View? If not, it might be easier to just filter the View itself to those items where the currently logged in user is the assignee (e.g. `AssignedTo=[Me]`)